# SonarQube with FindBugs Plugin

Tags: java, static-analysis, sonarqube, findbugs

I am having serious major difficulties configuring *SonarQube* to use the *FindBugs* plugin. I know that this 1) requires the location of the binaries (.class files) to be explicitly defined in the sonar-project.properties file. My problem is that I have a huge amount of source code to scan with binaries located throughout the project. There are also .jars and .war files. Also, the entire project is in a .ear file.

I have had success using the *FindBugs* plugin with *SonarQube* when there is a single source file (.java) and a single binary (.class file). My problems arise when there is more than one binary and more than one class file that are all hidden through the various directories of a large project.

**My Main Questions:**
Can anyone tell me how to configure the properties file correctly to specify where to find the binaries? Does *findbugs* need the location of every single binary or just a few binaries? Can I group all the binaries into one location or do they need a specific directory structure? Should I specify the entire relative path to the binaries or is something different needed?

Thank-you for reading this. Also, is it easier to use *FindBugs* with *Maven* instead of *Sonar-Runner* to analyse source code for problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify `sonar.libraries` property too.

> "Comma-separated paths to files with third-party libraries. This property is used by rule engines during issues detection (mainly the SonarQube and FindBugs engines, which both rely on bytecode)."

Details: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters .

Or use maven based analyzes that collects the dependencies automatically. But I'm not sure that findbugs can handle this correctly.